# SAP Hybris CCv2 deploy failing with Cannot invoke "java.lang.Iterable.iterator()" because "values" is null

Tags: e-commerce, sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to deploy an upgraded package from 6.7 to 2105. After restoring the production DB when I try to deploy it is failing with below error:
Cannot invoke "java.lang.Iterable.iterator()" because "values" is null

Below a larger snippet of the stack. Some new ideas would be appreaciated. Thanks!

Unexporting the registry.   INFO
March 1st 2022, 16:14:59.340     -   -  AfterSaveEventPublisher-master has been interrupted - stopping now: sleep interrupted   INFO
March 1st 2022, 16:14:59.340     -   -  AfterSaveEventPublisher-master has been interrupted/terminated but without InterruptedException - stopping now. INFO
March 1st 2022, 16:14:58.538     -   -  Cannot invoke "java.lang.Iterable.iterator()" because "values" is null  ERROR
March 1st 2022, 16:14:58.538     -   -  Error occurred while performing ant task    ERROR
March 1st 2022, 16:14:58.538     -   -  Task engine already stopped.    INFO
March 1st 2022, 16:14:58.538     -   -  Stopping Solr clients clean-up thread for tenant master